# Rspec test failing in docker but passing locally - present? method is funky

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
describe '#generate_authorization' do
  it 'creates document authorization' do
    loan.generate_authorization(admin)

    expect(Document::Authorization.count).to eq(1)
    expect(File.exist?(template_filled_pdf)).to eq false

    # the line below fails in Docker but passes on my local environment
    expect(loan.reload.authorization.present?).to eq true
  end
end
```

I have a weird issue where my spec started failing ever since I moved my project into a docker container.

What's even more weird is that when I put in a binding.pry to inspect my loan object, `loan.authorization` returns an object, but upon calling `.present?`, it returns false.

I am not overriding the `present?` method, but here is my biggest wtf moment:

```
loan.authorization.present?
=> false
loan.authorization.id.present?
=> true
```

Do you guys know what might be happening here?

Comment: What do you get for loan.authorization.class ?

Comment: @AntarrByrd It returns the correct class (in my case, `Document::Authorization`). I can access all the attributes just fine and calling reload on it shows that it is still there.

Comment: If you are using `pry` maybe try calling `show-source loan.authorization.present?` at the break point, to see make sure that method that is being used is the one you expect. This is just a sanity check.